# Materialize alignment issue with cards

Tags: html, css, materialize

Hey guys I'm using the materialize framework and I added some normal image cards like this.

[image: screenshot]

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/websiteicon.png" alt="websites">
                <span class="card-title">title here</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="diensten.php">check out possibilities</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 (4 div cards)
 </div>
```

This only appears at the medium browser size and only at certain widths.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Pretty sure it's not a bug.

Comment: Are you mixing Material with Bootstrap?

Comment: @NitinDhomse nope only custom css and Materialize. (+ javascript from jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your cards have different heights, which causes some cards to appear on the wrong "row". The reason it only appears on certain widths is because of the content reflowing, causing the parent element to expand in height.

There are a couple of ways you can solve this. You can make use of Materializes [card size](http://materializecss.com/cards.html). This sets the card to a static height, but if you need to display a lot of content I would not recommend it.

```
<div class="card medium">
 ...    
</div>
```

Another way to solve this is by adding another level of rows, grouping (as an example) 2 cards. If you use the correct size on the columns (2 cards with .m6, 3 with .m4, 4 cards with .m3 and so on) it will not cause the content of the row to wrap to a second row.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="row col s12 m12 l6"> <!--1st row containing 2 cards-->
  <div class="col s12 m6 card">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 card">
   ...
  </div>
 </div><!--END ROW-->

 <div class="row col s12 m12 l6">  <!--2nd row containing 2 cards-->
  <div class="col s12 m6 card">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6 card">
   ...
  </div>
 </div><!--END ROW-->
</div
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/DehraX/pen/LkQBwZ

Comment: The first one will not work for my amount of text, but the second method works, except for one problem. When I have fullscreen browser window I want them to appear in one row with four cards next to eachother. (medium 2 cards next to eachother and small 1 card)

Comment: @Veslav I have updated with another set of classes. Could you visualize what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Veslav The updated classes did the trick. But you have to add some custom CSS to fix the margin differences. http://codepen.io/DehraX/pen/LkQBwZ

Comment: that will work, thanks! Only need to add some margins to make it look better now.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this if someone else needs some help:

http://codepen.io/TrueNorth/pen/MwVoYp

```
hope it helped
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. It turned out that I had put a margin on another element on the page but it didn't show up and I forgot about it. After testing the cards in isolation, I eventually found the margin and deleted it and it went back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that all is good here. Here is the screenshot of same code like yours.

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTULo.png)

Comment: This isn't really and answer, it should go in the comments under the question :-)

Comment: what I meant was that I had my browser window smaller so they would go in two rows next to eachother instead of four. Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: @KresoGalic yes that will work, but I have like 200 characters in one and 400 in the other so there is a difference in size.

Comment: @Veslav then take card reveal component from materialize css and that will resolve your problems

Comment: @Veslav you can try to cut your text with this trick https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @KresoGalic I would like to let the people see all the text I currently have.   It's like a promotion part of the website. But a reveal might do the trick if no-one finds anything better.

Comment: @Veslav this is what i suggest, show 2-3 lines of text, and then on hover show all text something like this effect http://codepen.io/hemmingsson/pen/oxdbbg or something like this http://codepen.io/omgmog/pen/xGVgqG

Comment: @KresoGalic thanks for that. I'll look into it. Don't know if I'll use it but it looks really nice. (thinking about issues with mobile)